# Adjust wait_time in locust using custom arguments via CLI

Tags: locust

I want to adjust wait_time parameter by passing it via CLI.

I have tried the following way:

```py
custom_wait_time = None

# Add custom argument to locust
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def init_parser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--locust-wait-time",
                      type=int,
                      include_in_web_ui=True,
                      default=None,
                      help="Wait time per each request of a user.")

@events.init.add_listener
def _(environment, **kwargs):
    global custom_wait_time
    custom_wait_time = int(environment.parsed_options.locust_wait_time)
    print(custom_wait_time) # First print

class MyUser(HttpUser):
    global custom_wait_time
    print(custom_wait_time) # Second print
    wait_time = constant(custom_wait_time)
```

Assume that custom_wait_time=10 when I pass it via CLI, the First print gives me custom_wait_time=10 while the Second print gives me custom_wait_time=None instead of 10, so the `wait_time = constant(custom_wait_time)` will break and give me the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/users.py", line 176, in run_user
    user.run()
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/users.py", line 144, in run
    self._taskset_instance.run()
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 367, in run
    self.wait()
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 445, in wait
    self._sleep(self.wait_time())
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 451, in _sleep
    gevent.sleep(seconds)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 157, in sleep
    if seconds <= 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code will run in the wrong order - MyUser is defined *before* any of the init-methods are called.

If you instead do `MyUser.wait_time = constant(custom_wait_time)` inside your `init` handler (and dont set it at all in the class) it should work.

That way you dont need any globals either :)

Comment: Many thanks, I've followed your instruction and it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I've just do the same work.

```
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def _(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--waitTime", type=float, env_var="LOCUST_WAIT_TIME", default=1.0, help="wait time between each task of an user")
    # Set `include_in_web_ui` to False if you want to hide from the web UI
    #parser.add_argument("--my-ui-invisible-argument", include_in_web_ui=False, default="I am invisible")
```

and in the test class, just use it value like this

```
class GetInfoUser(HttpUser):  
  def wait_time(self):
    return self.environment.parsed_options.waitTime
```

Comment: So the `wait_time(self)` is the same as setting private variable `wait_time` in GetInfoUser right ?

Comment: Yep, it will set wait_time in GetInfoUser class to the same value as env waitTime